# django-facebook library errors.

Tags: django, facebook, django-facebook

I am using django_facebook to connect with Facebook from my Django app.

I am using `@facebook_required(scope='publish_stream,user_photos')` before my view function.

```
@facebook_required(scope='publish_stream,user_photos')
def sport(request, sport):
    """ Default view for the root """
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print "I am authenticated"
        print request.user
    sport_template = ".".join([sport, "html"])
    sport_name = ' '.join(sport.split('-'))
    return render(request, sport_template, {'sport_name': sport_name})
```

`print request.user` always returns AnonymousUser, even after successful Facebook login.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some brackets. Try: `request.user.is_authenticated()`.

Comment: for python that should be fine

Comment: Do you mean that it should be fine without brackets? It definitely shouldn't. You may be confusing the `request.user.is_authenticated()` function with Django's templating property `{{ user.is_authenticated }}`.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. Now view function is not printing "I am authenticated", seems like no authentication/login is happening with facebook.